# USB mouse stopped working in Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: mouse, docker, mongodb

My USB mouse has stopped working today. Although touchpad is still working, I am satisfied with that. Also I cannot install MongoDB on Ubuntu 22.10. I don't want to use docker as it takes too many resources.

I'm using a normal traditional wired USB mouse like the one given below on the link:

https://ict.com.mm/products/sony-usb-mouse

Answer (score 1):

I also have this problem.

Temp solution is to switch to text mode and back via CTL ALT F7 followed by CTL ALT F1.

Not sure how to fix this for real though.

Comment: yes, it  is not working cuz your shortcut only logout the  system